# Proper AJAX and PHP mysqli query request ratio

Tags: php, ajax, mysqli, client-server

I have a client that needs to retrieve information from various tables in a mysqli database on a web server. I currently have one AJAX query set up on the client that posts an AJAX request to a php page that queries the database and returns a JSON object. The client then iterates through the resulting object and inserts the necessary data into a similar table in a local database. However this query only contains information from one table. I am going to need to populate multiple tables in the client database. Eventually there could be a large amount of requests to the web server occurring at one time when populating these database. The possible solutions that I've come up with are as follows:

1. Design multiple ajax queries on the client that each post to the same php page with separate handler queries depending on the type of post received so that different JSON objects are returned for the client to iterate and insert into the local database
   (Many AJAX -> 1 PHP)
2. Design many AJAX queries that each post to a different php page with a single resulting JSON for each AJAX/PHP query to reduce the traffic on any single PHP page.
   (Many AJAX -> Many PHP)
3. Design 1 large AJAX query that makes a single request to the PHP page and returns all the necessary information from the database and have the client insert the different pieces it needs into the local database.
   (1 AJAX -> 1 PHP)

Do any of these ideas seem better than the others?
I see flaws in all of them so I'm wondering if there is already an ideal solution to minimize the amount of work done on the client as well as reduce the traffic/maintenance on the server that someone may know of. Any help/criticism is appreciated.

Comment: I'd suggest, one PHP page that is posted by a lot of ajax queries.

Answer (score 0):

Options 1 and 3 are not mutually exclusive: your server-side code can return small (or partial, depends on how you see it) data sets as in option 1 and at the same time reply to a different type of request with the full data set. The client-side code decides what query to make depending on information that it has regarding the operation being performed. For example, it might use one query if the requested operation was "update one record" and another if the operation was "update all records".

Broadly speaking that's what I would do, so I recommend to leave yourself the flexibility to choose the appropriate query type down the road.